# Handling unseen classes with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I made a Keras model with Python that classifies if string input is company, person or address.
Model is trained on 12000 string data. Each input has between 1 and 5 words.
This is the model:

```
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector char', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3, 6), max_features = 2000), 'text'),
                                                        ('vector word', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 4000), 'text')],
                                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns


features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = features.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(200, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

These are the results:

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

company         0.97         0.92      0.95       636
person          0.93         0.97      0.95       697
address         1.00         1.00      1.00       667

accuracy                               0.97      2000
macro avg       0.97         0.96      0.97      2000
weighted avg    0.97         0.97      0.97      2000
```

So for example if I want to make prediction with string input:

```
input_strs = ['Amazon Inc', 'Jeff Bezos', 'Elon Musk', '24 Avenue Paris']
```

It classifies it as:

```
 ['company', 'person', 'person', 'address']
```

The model works good, but I noticed that sometimes it makes big mistake if I enter a string that, for example, represents phone number or just some random numbers, or some random string.
For example if I enter:

```
['+435 542 425 54 24', '426266245', 'as long as the']
```

I get the result:

```
 ['address', 'company', 'address']
```

My question is, how can I handle some unseen classes?
How can I handle the situation if string input does not satisfy some basic 'form' that can be classified properly?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you make one category named "hmmm..." or the like. And - fill this category with huge number of strings which DO NOT belong to classes of your interest.

It is easy to make a small script which reads the internet or books for a while and every time it finds a string which is not company, address or person, then it saves it to the "hmmm..." category.

As a result you have a DNN which classifies every "weird" input to class "hmmm...."

You can find also other solutions but this would be one way to manage that.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I do not think that its a good solution. I need to collect dates, phone numbers, random numbers, and a lot of different strings and to put them in one class, there must be a better solution

Comment: I'll provide you with an alternative solution, as an independent answer. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Another - more straightforward but I think not so accurate solution in long term - is to add some simple logic after the softmax somehow by the following way:

```
import numpy as np

#Initialize
softmaxoutput=np.double([1,2,3])
classes=['company','person','address']

#Let's play a littlebit with the outputs
softmaxoutput[0]=0.3
softmaxoutput[1]=0.3
softmaxoutput[2]=1-(softmaxoutput[0]+softmaxoutput[1])

#Let's decide the predicted class...
result=np.argmax(softmaxoutput)
predicted_class=classes[result]

uncertainity_threshold=0.5

#...but make an exception that...
if np.amax(softmaxoutput)<=uncertainity_threshold:
    predicted_class='hmmm...'

#And finally let's show the result
print(predicted_class)
```

...you can easily manage the "effect" of this additional logic by the parameter uncertainity_threshold. If you put this to value of 1, you'll surely get the same results like in you current solution...but by diminishing this value lower your headache about nonlogical classifications will slightly relieve. It is simple to test "by hand" what seems to be the optimal value.

You can find also other solutions but this would be a second way to manage that problem.